# TestLink Installation script shows its source code instead of running

Tags: php, apache, testlink

I'm trying to install TestLink 1.9.7 but the index.php script in the Install folder only shows the source code. I've read a question ticket on StackOverflow about a similar problem with PHPMyAdmin but the solution (enabling short tags in php.ini) didn't work for me. the file install/index.php still won't execute.

I've installed the following prior to testlink:
Apache 2.2.25,
PHP 5.3.27,
MySQL Server 5.6.12.2(Web Community)

This is all that the installation manual for testlink tells me to install. I believe something else is missing. Is there any setting in Apache that I should change, or any service I need to enable?

Edit: I've read the instructions on php.net on how to configure Apache to work with PHP, however the section about configuring it as handler cause the Apache server to fail to restart and the section about configuration as CGI contains insufficient instructions(like which files to copy over and how to edit them).

Comment: Have you configured Apache to execute PHP scripts?

Comment: No, this is all actually quite new to me, so I don't know how to configure the server to do that. How should I do that?

Comment: In the Apache configuration file, find a line `LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` and uncomment it. Then, add the lines `<FilesMatch \.php$>`, `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` and `</FilesMatch>`. Your installation might also provide a file named `<something>php<something>`, which you have to link into the directory with the configuration files to use.

Comment: There is no such line as "LoadModule php5_module lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so", should I add it to the file? (also the same for <something>php<something>

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that the module path might be different in your installation.

Comment: Where should I look to find out?

Comment: In the file should be more lines starting with `LoadModule`. Have you installed Apache via package manager?

Comment: the Apache installer is a .msi file if that's of any importance. And I've never heard of this "package manager". Also I think I might've installed something improperly due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Okay. I cannot really help with Apache on Windows, but you might want to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php) for details on how to configure Apache PHP support. BTW: A package manager is used in many UN*X-like operating systems for installing and maintaining software.

Comment: Okay, i'll have a look at that. thanks!